# Visualizing and understanding a fast-forward in git

Tags: git, version-control

I just fetched from origin and `git status` reports:

> Your branch is behind origin/ by 13 commits, and can be
>   fast-forwarded

Strictly speaking, what does this *exactly* mean? Does it mean:

1. that `HEAD` is behind the corresponding **remote-tracking-branch** (`origin/<branch_name>`).
2. or that `<branch_name>` is behind the corresponding **remote-tracking-branch** (`origin/<branch_name>`)?

What if I am on a **detached** `HEAD`? (i.e. if my `HEAD` and `<branch_name>` don't point to the same commit).

Is there a way to visualize these pointers (`HEAD`, `<branch_name>` and `origin/<branch_name>` on a graph? I have tried with `git log --graph`, but I think I only see the different commits and they merge overtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at an example. This repository has a remote called `origin` with a branch called `master`. I also have a branch called `master` which I currently have checked out.

```
% git log --decorate --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
* 072a57a (origin/master, origin/HEAD) C
* 87011c4 B
* d3c4a48 (HEAD, master) A
```

When I run `git status` it tells me that my branch `master` is behind `origin/master` by two commits.

```
% git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: Thanks. What does `A`, `B` and `C` mean in the first graph in your answer?

Comment: They are the commit messages.

Comment: Thanks! Visualizing the graph is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

"Your branch" means the branch that your are on so `HEAD` is pointing at `<branch_name>` and 1 and 2 mean the same thing. (`git status` only reports about the status of the branch you are on, not all local branches.)

The message means that your branch is a pointing to a commit that is a direct ancestor of the remote branch head, so it points to a commit somewhere on the network of parent commits of the head of the remote branch. It's nothing more complicated than this.

If you received the message while you were on a detached head then you should log a bug - it shouldn't happen.

Note that your branch name doesn't have to match the branch name on the remote - the message will tell you that `<alt-branch-name>` is behind `origin/<branch-name>` provided that `<alt-branch-name>` is tracking `origin/<branch-name>`.